# Angular fadein and fadeout - the standard way without CSS?

Tags: angularjs, fadein, angularjs-animation

I find it extremely difficult to make an animation in angular, comparing to jquery. There are so many versions of angular animation fadein and fadeout that I found them from blogs/ tutorials/ etc, some of them are on older version of angular. Angular's seems to be very inconsistent when a newer version of it comes out to replace the old ones. I can't see any standard way of doing it. Hence I don't know where to start.

I just to fade in a form or a html doc when the button is clicked.

html,

```
<button ng-click="loadInclude" >Load Include Form</button>
<div ng-include="'form.php'" ng-if="readyToLoadForm===true"></div>
```

angular,

```
   var app = angular.module("myapp", ['ngAnimate']);

   app.controller("FormController",function($scope) {

            $scope.readyToLoadForm = false;
            $scope.loadInclude = function(e) {
                $scope.readyToLoadForm = true;
            };
        }
    );
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use a `ng-show` or `ng-hide` in this case

```
<div ng-show="readyToLoadForm" class="animate-show animate-hide">TEST HERE</div>
```

when using `angular-animate.js` angular will `add` and `remove` several classes to this item when showing and hiding. based on that classes we can set a css animation to the element.

here is a simple [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BCHK0fcMZHx4VVJZrgP8?p=preview)

---

**for `ng-include` animation**

`ng-leave` `.ng-leave-active` `.ng-enter-active` classes add to the element. there is a little desc about classes added when animating. and that desc is from [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate)

here is the  `ng-enter` demo [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YoOgdLukfbjgrAl2lpat?p=preview)

---

here is the [reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate) for how the classes assigned to the element when animation elements in angularjs

Comment: Thanks for the update. I keep getting this error `Error: $animate.enter(...) is undefined` - it seems that it is a version problem or something else!

Comment: got it working now. it is caused by the annoying differences in versions - `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular-animate.min.js`- just as I said before. anyway thanks. Angular is really a pain in the a** even though it is a perfect framework.